# How to build OpenJDK with Emscripten?

Tags: java, webassembly

I am trying to use Emscripten's emconfigure and emmake to compile OpenJDK for the web. The end goal would be to be able to run uncompiled java code natively in the browser. However, running `emconfigure ./configure` throws the error

```
configure: The C compiler (located as /usr/lib/emscripten/emcc) does not seem to be the required gcc compiler.
configure: The result from running with --version was: ""
configure: error: A gcc compiler is required. Try setting --with-tools-dir.
```

I have been searching all day and I haven't found anything along the lines of this error. Is there any easy workaround for this? Should I even be trying to build OpenJDK this way?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any easy workaround for this?

I doubt it.  If you look at (for example) `jdk11u/make/autoconf/toolchain.m4` you will see the toolchains that are supported on various platforms.  Emscripten is not listed.

I expect that `emconfigure` is trying to use the JDK's autoconf-based configuration framework.   And that framework is checking the compiler you are trying to use ... and saying Nope!

You may be able to modify the auto-conf macros to support the Emscripten tool chain.  But the next problem will be getting the code to actually compile.   And then to getting it to run.

> Should I even be trying to build OpenJDK this way?

It is not up to us to say what you *should* do.

However, I would make some observations.

1. If you are expecting this to work without significant effort, you are sadly mistaken.

   What you are doing is equivalent to trying to port Java to a new OP platform and hardware platform.  This is is a massive project.  In addition to just getting the JVM to compile, you also have the problem of getting the Hotspot JIT compiler to generate WebAssembly code.
2. This is probably a bad idea anyway.  Once upon a time, mainstream web browser vendors did support Java in the browser.  But there were so many "security issues" that (virtually) all vendors have dropped support.  Oracle saw the writing on the wall, and in Java 9 they started the process of removing support from the OpenJDK codebase.  Applet support and JNLP are gone, and they are planning to get rid of the `SecurityManager` framework.

   What you would be doing is bring back Java support in the web browser ... with the security safeguards stripped out.

   Basically, the Java SE platform is to rich to implement securely in a web browser.

---

If you are still keen on building a JVM using Emscripten, take a look at https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/3342.

But note that they are talking about building JamVM, which is Java 1.6, and hasn't been touched since 2014.